# FLEX is not showing image

Tags: image, apache-flex

Flex is not showing image I have tried many webpages for helping can anyone please help me

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
        <mx:Script><![CDATA[
            public var photo:FileReference = new FileReference();

            protected function crop_clickHandler():void
            {
                var f:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Image", "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*;*.gif;*.png;");
                photo.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelected);
                photo.browse([f]);
            }

            private function fileSelected(evt:Event):void
            {
                photo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loadCompleted);
                photo.load();
            }

            private var loader : Loader = new Loader();

            private function loadCompleted(evt:Event):void
            {
                loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getBitmapData);
                loader.loadBytes(photo.data);

            }

            private function getBitmapData(event:Event):void
            {
                var content:DisplayObject = loader.content;
                var BMPData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(content.width,content.height);

                //  var imgObj:Object = new Object();
                var bmd:BitmapData;
                bmd = Bitmap(event.currentTarget.content).bitmapData;
                var bmpMy:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
                myImage1.source=bmpMy
                // myImage1.addChild(DisplayObject(bmpMy));


            }
            ]]></mx:Script>
```

**I have even tried to show the image here after the load but it is not working the way I tried**

```
        <mx:Button id="btnLoad" label="Browse Image" click="crop_clickHandler()" ></mx:Button>
        <mx:Image id="myImage1" x="50" y="50" height="100%" width="100%" maintainAspectRatio="false" autoLoad="true" ></mx:Image>

    </mx:Application>
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you're trying to do. You have provided a significant amount of code just to display an image. Are you trying to display an image from your user's local machine?

Comment: It worked just fine for me. I just copy/pasted your exact code. You are running this in an AIR app right? You are accessing methods of FileReference that are only available through AIR... edit.. never mind, I can tell you are not as per mx:Application tag..

Comment: Reboog711 you are right i am uploading an image from my local machine and showing the same image which i have loaded   Thanks for your reply

Comment: drkstr1 I am just trying with mxml compiler is it a right way or i have to use some other ways if so please guide me on it Thanks for your reply

Comment: guyz @drkstr1 and Reboog711 help me out,eagerly waiting for your reply

Comment: @Suriyanarayanan Sorry I was mistaken about the AIR functionality. It's actually a player version issue. See answer bellow for details.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing methods on FileReference that are not available in flash player 9 (the default for Flex 3.6).

What you need to do is target flash player 10.1 or later. Here are the instructions to target 11.1, as that's what comes with Flex 4.

First, Update the target player under "Flex Compiler" in project properties:

[image]

Second, go to Flex Build Path and remove playerglobal.swc from under the Flex 3.6a menu. Then click Add SWC and select the playerglobal.swc for the targeted player version (look in FLEX_SDK/frameworks/libs/player/11.1).

[image]

Don't forget to do a Project Clean afterwards.

You should now be able to run your code as is.

Comment: Thanks Much I will try the things which u have guided hope this works for me !!!!!!!!